# Listview Textview Strikethrough

Tags: android, listview, textview, strikethrough

Hello is it possible to have a listview containing textview be strikethrough ?

for example

```
if(itemText.equals("Done")){
//  strikethrough here. 
}else{
// no strikethrought here. 
}
```

the thing is, when I do this the item plus the first index of the listview gets strike through

[image]

is there a way to only strike the click item ?

please help me thank you

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of what you have currently? I'm struggling to understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: i have low reputation i cant post image anyway heres what happens, i put the code and not only the word "Done" is strike also the first index of the listview

Comment: What do you mean by the first index? Also to upload a screenshot, you can add a link that references some other destination like Dropbox for example and then simply upload the image into your Dropbox.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xejbsy1n9dj9rw6/SC20131108-231216.png heres the link

Comment: is thers a way to only strike the selected item / child on listview ?

Comment: There aren't any children? Oh and nice job on sorting the screenshot. Learn something new every day. :D

Comment: so any idea on how to fix this ? thanks

Comment: I want to help but I'm still not understanding what's wrong. I presume the three words you have in the screenshot are like expandable listviews or something and you want their children to be striked through?

Comment: Is the Extra bit, the thing that looks like a button, the child of the 'Extra' parent?

Comment: idk whats expandable listview, but user type task there and click when thats done, when u click task it will turn into "done" text, i just put not done to be more dramatic and descriptive about the problem.

Comment: I'm still unclear haha. What exactly do you want to have a strikethrough in that screenshot?

Comment: yes it is also part of the listview, and as you see its strike through though its not settext as "Done". the only way to get rid of this is to have the index of the textview inside the listview, and thats what im asking for.

Comment: only the child that have "done" text sir,

Comment: Not going to lie, this isn't making much sense to me, sorry. Can you annotate the screenshot and upload another, displaying what you want it to look like? Maybe do it using Paint or something similar.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7kg4swt6hdafmqz/SC20131108-234124.png heres the new and i wish you understand

Comment: Okay, so I'm guessing you don't want the others to be striked through like in the first screenshot. You only want one to be? How is it being striked anyway, by clicking on it?

Comment: yes ! so any idea how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I've finally understood what you want done. But here's a shot:

You have to add an onListItemClick method like so:

```
  @Override
  public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {        
      super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

      TextView item = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
      item.setPaintFlags(item.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
  }
```

Hopefully this is what you wanted as I've got it in one of my apps and it works perfectly. Let me know! Hope it does.

Comment: Thanks, though i editted something cuz your answer should be on ListActivity and Im on Activity so I create a new Listener for the listview, anyway, same logic as yours thanks. You help a lot. :D

Comment: Ha no worries man. Does it actually work now? I hope it helped. I know how frustrating it is when you can't get something to work. Any chance of an up vote too? :P

Comment: sorry my rep are pretty low, ill do when it drops 15, yeah that actually work, can i have your email so i can contact there if i have a question if thats ok with you, thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries man! Yeah sure, my email is on my profile. Just email me the  question URL when you have a new question. That way we both still benefit reputation. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you want, but to display a strikethrough text in a textview, you can:

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

To undo the strike through:

```
textView.setPaintFlags(textView.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
```

Comment: yes but what do this is strike all textview inside listview what i need is just the child of the listview

Comment: He knows how to strikethrough, he's just striking through the wrong item.

Comment: so is theres a way to tell it that this item of listview to strikethrrough? i tried listview.setItemOnClick but not work either

Comment: if theres only a textview.getlistviewindex or something like that function